# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server error in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to resolve the following Error

> "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)"

Here is my web.config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="paconn" connectionString="Data Source=XYZ-PC;Initial Catalog=crm;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User ID=sa;Password=xyz@123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="60000" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and my C# code that throws the error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class autorefresh_create_emi : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["paconn"].ToString());
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select max(f_casenum) from c_detail", con);
        string check_max = com1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        if (check_max == "0")
        {
        }
        else
        {
            string st_id = "";
            Int64 st = 0;
            string max_id = "";
            Int64 en = 0;

            SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("select top 1(f_casenum) from c_emi where f_casenum not in (select top 1 (f_casenum) from c_detail order by f_casenum) order by f_casenum", con);
            st_id = com2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            st_id = st_id.Substring(2);
            st = Convert.ToInt64(st_id);

            max_id = check_max;
            max_id = max_id.Substring(2);
            en = Convert.ToInt64(max_id);

            for (Int64 i = st; i <= en; i++)
            {
                string f_casenum = "PA" + i;
                string c_status = "";
                string f_tenure = "";

                SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand("select * from c_detail where f_casenum=@f_casenum", con);
                com3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_casenum", f_casenum);

                SqlDataReader reader3 = com3.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader3.Read())
                {
                    f_tenure = reader3["f_tenure"].ToString().Trim();
                    c_status = reader3["c_status"].ToString();
                }

                if (c_status == "Full Paid")
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    string row_check = "";
                    SqlCommand com4 = new SqlCommand("select count(f_invoice) from c_emi where f_casenum=@f_casenum", con);
                    com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_casenum", f_casenum);
                    row_check = com4.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Trim();

                    if (f_tenure.Equals(row_check))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string st_id_invoice = "";
                        Int64 st_invoice = 0;
                        string max_id_invoice = "";
                        Int64 en_invoice = 0;

                        SqlCommand com5 = new SqlCommand("select min(f_invoice) from c_emi where f_casenum=@f_casenum", con);
                        com5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_casenum", f_casenum);
                        st_id_invoice = com5.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                        st_id_invoice = st_id_invoice.Substring(3);
                        st_invoice = Convert.ToInt64(st_id_invoice);

                        SqlCommand com6 = new SqlCommand("select max(f_invoice) from c_emi where f_casenum=@f_casenum", con);
                        com6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_casenum", f_casenum);
                        max_id_invoice = com6.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                        max_id_invoice = max_id_invoice.Substring(3);
                        en_invoice = Convert.ToInt64(max_id_invoice);

                        for (Int64 j = st_invoice; j <= en_invoice; j++)
                        {
                            string invoice_date = "";
                            string f_emi_due = "";
                            string f_total_emi = "";
                            string f_emi = "";
                            string f_b_curr = "";

                            string f_invoice = "PAI" + j;
                            string f_casenum1 = "";

                            SqlCommand com7 = new SqlCommand("select * from c_emi where f_invoice=@f_invoice", con);
                            com7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_invoice", f_invoice);

                            SqlDataReader reader7 = com7.ExecuteReader();
                            if (reader7.Read())
                            {
                                f_casenum1 = reader7["f_casenum"].ToString();
                                f_emi = reader7["f_emi"].ToString();
                                f_emi_due = reader7["f_emi_due"].ToString();
                                f_total_emi = reader7["f_total_emi"].ToString();
                                f_b_curr = reader7["f_b_curr"].ToString();
                                invoice_date = reader7["invoice_date"].ToString();
                            }

                            if (f_casenum == f_casenum1)
                            {
                                DateTime currr = DateTime.Now;
                                DateTime INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currr, "India Standard Time");

                                DateTime curr = INDIAN_ZONE;
                                string curr_invoicedate = curr.ToShortDateString();
                                DateTime check_invoicedate = Convert.ToDateTime(invoice_date);
                                check_invoicedate = check_invoicedate.AddDays(30);
                                check_invoicedate = Convert.ToDateTime(check_invoicedate);
                                string exit_date = check_invoicedate.ToShortDateString();

                                string f_emi_duedate = check_invoicedate.AddDays(10).ToShortDateString();
                                string invoice_date1 = check_invoicedate.ToShortDateString();

                                SqlCommand com8 = new SqlCommand("select f_casenum from c_emi where f_casenum=@f_casenum and CONVERT(date,invoice_date,101)=@invoice_date", con);
                                com8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_casenum", f_casenum);
                                com8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoice_date", exit_date);

                                string check_exitdate = "";

                                SqlDataReader reader8 = com8.ExecuteReader();
                                if (reader8.Read())
                                {
                                    check_exitdate = reader8["f_casenum"].ToString();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                }

                                if (check_exitdate != "")
                                {
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (curr >= check_invoicedate)
                                    {
                                        string value = "0";
                                        string owner = "";
                                        string i_status = "Unlock";

                                        SqlCommand com9 = new SqlCommand("select MAX(f_invoice) from c_emi", con);
                                        string maxid1 = com9.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                                        string id1 = maxid1;
                                        Int64 code = 100000000001;
                                        string c = "PAI";

                                        if (id1.Substring(0, 1) != "P")
                                        {
                                            id1 = code.ToString();
                                            id1 = c + id1.ToString();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            id1 = id1.Substring(3);
                                            Int64 a = Convert.ToInt64(id1);
                                            a = a + 1;
                                            id1 = c + a.ToString();
                                        }
                                        id1 = id1.ToString();

                                        SqlCommand com11 = new SqlCommand("insert into c_emi values(@f_casenum,@f_b_amt,@f_emi,@f_emi_duedate,@f_invoice,@invoice_date,@f_overdue_amt,@f_emi_paid,@f_emi_due,@f_total_emi,@f_b_curr,@i_status,@owner,@convi_charges,@paidemi_date)", con);

                                        SqlParameter obj1 = new SqlParameter("@f_casenum", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj1.Value = f_casenum;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj1);

                                        SqlParameter obj2 = new SqlParameter("@f_overdue_amt", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj2.Value = value;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj2);

                                        SqlParameter obj3 = new SqlParameter("@f_emi_paid", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj3.Value = value;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj3);

                                        SqlParameter obj4 = new SqlParameter("@f_emi_due", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj4.Value = value;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj4);

                                        SqlParameter obj5 = new SqlParameter("@f_total_emi", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj5.Value = f_emi;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj5);

                                        SqlParameter obj6 = new SqlParameter("@f_emi", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj6.Value = f_emi;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj6);

                                        SqlParameter obj7 = new SqlParameter("@f_emi_duedate", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj7.Value = f_emi_duedate;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj7);

                                        SqlParameter obj8 = new SqlParameter("@f_invoice", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj8.Value = id1;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj8);

                                        SqlParameter obj9 = new SqlParameter("@invoice_date", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj9.Value = invoice_date1;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj9);

                                        SqlParameter obj10 = new SqlParameter("@f_b_amt", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj10.Value = f_b_curr;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj10);

                                        SqlParameter obj11 = new SqlParameter("@f_b_curr", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj11.Value = f_b_curr;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj11);

                                        SqlParameter obj12 = new SqlParameter("@i_status", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj12.Value = i_status;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj12);

                                        SqlParameter obj13 = new SqlParameter("@owner", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj13.Value = owner;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj13);

                                        SqlParameter obj14 = new SqlParameter("@convi_charges", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj14.Value = value;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj14);

                                        SqlParameter obj15 = new SqlParameter("@paidemi_date", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj15.Value = owner;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj15);

                                        com11.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

In line

```
SqlDataReader reader7 = com7.ExecuteReader();
```

Error Description :

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +388
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +815
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error) +817
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync() +344
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket() +48
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer() +72
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value) +114
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +950
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +69
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +134
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6553981
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +6556619
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +586
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +104
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +288
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +302
   autorefresh_create_emi.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\phurti_crm\autorefresh_create_emi.aspx.cs:106
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

I am using ASP.Net with C# and Database is SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log.  This could be an indication that the connection was killed or there was a problem on the server side, such as an access violation.

Comment: Check SQL service configuration, is it TCP based, named pipe etc.., there might be some different setting, that is blocking connection.

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP how to check it for SQL Server Error Log?

Comment: @ArindamNayak Protocol for SQLEXPRESS:TCP/IP and Named Pipes is Disable and Shared Memory Enable, MSSQLSERVER: TCP/IP and Named Pipes is Disable and Shared Memory Enable

Comment: The SQL Server error log can be viewed from SQL Server Management Studio or via a text editor.  The current file is named ERRORLOG (no extension) and the default location is in the SQL Server instance directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log).

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP Yes there is a file with name ERRORLOG and ERRORLOG.1 ERRORLOG.2 ERRORLOG.3 also. So what i do?

Comment: @user3441151, from your reply, it seems there are 2 instance of SQL server, make sure you are connecting the one, whose service is running. Regarding error log, please read that log file, see if there is any helpful thing, post here.

Comment: @User3441151, view the file named ERRORLOG with a text editor like notepad to see if there are error messages correlating to your transport error timeframe.

Comment: @ArindamNayak I post my ErrorLog file description in below, please tell me whats wrong?

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP In my ERRORLOG file description spid7s      Server resumed execution after being idle 8227 seconds. Reason: timer event.
Server      Server resumed execution after being idle 38837 seconds: user activity awakened the server. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
Logon       Error: 17889, Severity: 16, State: 1.
Logon       A new connection was rejected because the maximum number of connections on session ID 51 has been reached. Close an existing connection on this session and retry. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this issue using

```
reader.Close();
```

thanks for your support.